# can I save an entire scrollpane as "pdf"?

Tags: java, pdf, javafx, save, filechooser

I have been working on javafx and I want to save an entire scrollpane as "pdf". Is there a way I can do it without printjob?just a save button and it'll directly save the pane as pdf to directory using file chooser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use [iText](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/Core) (and possibly instance of class [Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)) for example. Use iText and instance of Class Robot if you want to save an image of the scroll pane to a pdf file, otherwise you can just use iText.